# React-Native app doesn't display anything

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm an absolute newbie when it comes to react-native.  I've been following a tutorial, but not all of the code is provided.  I've done my best - the app compiles - but all I see is a blank white page in iOS simulator.  Can anyone help me understand why I'm not seeing the labels from the `SearchPage` component?

App.js:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

 'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  NavigatorIOS
} from 'react-native';

import SearchPage from './SearchPage';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
     <NavigatorIOS
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={
          {
            title: 'Property Finder',
            component: SearchPage,
          }
        } /> 
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  description: {
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#656565',
    marginTop: 65,
  },
});
```

SearchPage.js:

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
  Button,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';

export default class SearchPage extends Component<{}> {
    render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.description}>
            Search for houses to buy!
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.description}>
            Search by place-name or postcode.
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }


  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    description: {
      marginBottom: 20,
      fontSize: 18,
      textAlign: 'center',
      color: '#656565'
    },
    container: {
      padding: 30,
      marginTop: 65,
      alignItems: 'center'
    },
  });
```

If I replace App.render() with the guts of SearchPage.render(), then I do see the 2 labels.

The tutorial is iOS-specific.  Simulator is iPhone 6 iOS 11.2.
If any other info is needed please leave a comment.

Comment: 1. try change SearchPage into another components. is it working?
2. try to put SearchPage, in the same file. let's see if it is working.

Comment: @ArdiArdianto: If I comment out the `import SearchPage ...` line and add the `SearchPage` component to App.js (above the App class) - I get the same result: a blank white page.    --  As far as "try change SearchPage into another components" goes - I wouldn't have any idea how to do that yet.  Do you just mean to rename it? Or to try a different component - perhaps built in to the rn framework?

Comment: Are u removed the style from NavigatorIOS and run it?

Comment: Huh.  Good call.  Removing the style, for some reason, causes a gray bar to appear at the top with the "Property Finder" title in it.  The SearchPage labels still do not show up.

Comment: I tried removing all the styles from the View and Text elements - still nothing.

Comment: problems are in styles. :  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  }, . try to remove this

Comment: odd.  It suddenly started working.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: btw, try to use https://snack.expo.io/ , to share your code :D